# Content background cut off

Tags: css, background, scrollbar, overflow

Scroll to the right and you'll see the background is truncated:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.</p>
</div>
```

Why does it happen? What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code**

this is because `p` doesn't get its actual width

```
p {
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background: green;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it happen? What does `float: left;` do?

Comment: this is because p doesn't get its actual width.By applying float it gets its complete width

Answer (score 0):

use the `width` and `overflow` in the same element as `background`. i have edited the snippet

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It shrinks the space between the scrollbar and the text, i.e. the paragraph margin goes outside the scrollbar.

Comment: then, you can simply use `display: inline-block` for `<`p>`. but this is not a good idea to do it. if you need this kind of output, i recommend using `span` instead of `p`. i have edited the above snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <p>ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.</p>
</div>  


div {
      width: 300px;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    p {
      background: green;
    overflow: auto;
    }
```

Fiddler link https://jsfiddle.net/o0eqoqmh/

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just set p as inline or inline-block element

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
  /* OR 
  display: inline;
  */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.ThisIsSomeText.</p>
</div>
```